# Cache of a file editing by gedit on a mounted FTP?

Tags: gedit

I was working on a file live by editing changes to a file on FTP by mounting the FTP on Ubuntu and using gedit to make changes.

After work, I shut down my machine and now I realize that the file on FTP has been wiped of its content. Any ideas if gedit might have a cache copy of it?

Comment: Never edit files on mounted network drives. Although it often works, but when it doesn't, your content is nuked. Keep a local copy on your drive and push your changes when you are ready.

Answer (score 2):

If you have already shut down, there is unlikely to be any leftovers from any in-memory copies of the contents gedit was editing.

In gedit, there are preference options to create backup files.  Look for these options under Edit...Preferences...Editor.  If you happened to have turned on the autosave function, you may find a copy of the file with ~ appended to the name stored in the editing location (but in this case, I suspect you would have found it when looking at the FTP site).

In summary, probably not (and you probably already did something else to recover the content in the last 15 weeks), but if you set this option, you may discover that the answer is "Yes" in the future.